# NetBeans не выводит форму

Tags: java, netbeans

Учусь программировать на java, решил создать форму,создал JForm, добавил кнопку.
  При запуске проекта пишет сборка завершена успешно и всё, форма не выводится.
Смотрел на ютубе должна выводиться нормально, не могу понять в чём проблема.

Код который уже присутствует при создании формы.

```
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jButton1.setText("jButton1");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(133, 133, 133)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap(194, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(210, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addGap(67, 67, 67))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    }                                        


    public static void main(String args[]) {

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Сборка != запуск

Comment: А пример кода можно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В NetBeans выделите файл "NewJFrame.java" в панели "Projects".
Нажмите правую кнопку мышки и выберите из контекстного меню "Run File".
Вы также можете щелкнуть правой кнопкой мышки в любом месте открытого исходника и выбрать "Run File".

Прочитайте в документации, как скомпилировать и выполнить файл .java.
Посмотрите на wiki: ["Компиляция и запуск"](https://ru.wikihow.com/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%83-Java-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8)

Comment: Спасибо, теперь разобрался.